# UIGraphics, Make a Screenshot Of The Screen But Avoid UI Elements

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uiimageview

Building a feature, similar to Snapchat's stickers. 
Make a photo, add stickers(emoji), post the image. 
My current view hierarchy is:

- main View

  - view for user's photo
  - view for ui elements ('cancel/add stickers/post') + stickers/emoji also added to this view.

UIImageView for user's photo, takes up the whole screen just as in snapchat. 
UI elements are added in a different view but on top of the user's UIImageView.

My code for view screenshot:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if let imageToData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 0.2) {
        //saving imageToData to Firebase.    
    }
```

but this, gets everything that is in the main view, including UI elements.

One option is to limit user's UIImageView for photo so that UI elements aren't covering it. Then we can make a screenshot of that limited view. 
But that is not whats app's UX should be.

The other option, that I thought of - is to place user's UIImageView for photo on top of the view with UIElements. And then add all emojis to it. But that will cover all UI elements.

How to make a screenshot of user's UIImageView photo + emoji - UIElements?

Comment: What is "view" in the above code you've provided? Is that the `view` property of your `UIViewController`? Or, the view for the users's photo which contains the UIImageView + emoji? What you need is a subview with just the UIImageView and the emoji and to create an image from that subview.

Comment: 'view' - is property of UIViewController. 
You're suggesting  a subview with UIImageView with Emojis. But as I mentioned, I need UIImageView to be edge to edge. That said, If i would have another subview with UI elements - they will end up under the user's UIImageView. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, you would simply need to set up the image hierarchy as follows:

- main View (A)

  - Sub-view (B) set to stretch edge-to-edge for image and emojis

    - view (D) for user's photo
    - Stickers/emoji or any other design elements
  - view (C) for ui elements ('cancel/add stickers/post')

I do note that you said that you need the image view edge-to-edge and I don't see why that would be an issue for the above hierarchy unless I'm missing something since you can make subview B stretch side to side on the main view and then set the image view (D) to stretch edge-to-edge as well.

Here's some modified code based on your above code. In the following code, `viewB` is a reference to the B view.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewB.bounds.size, viewB.isOpaque, 0.0)
viewB.drawHierarchy(in: viewB.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

if let imageToData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 0.2) {
    //saving imageToData to Firebase.    
}
```

Comment: I see that you are suggesting to put UI elements on top of everything. 
My question then:  when I will call  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions woudn't it still include UI elements, since it has 'view.bounds.size' ? 
Or there is a way to exclude the top view with UI elements?

Comment: Just because the UI elements are above the image view, the should not get included in your image. Since you create an image of only the B view and it's subviews, only those would show up. The position (as in above/below) of the images does not matter - what matters is the hierarchy and you only create an image of the B view and its subviews. Please try this and see what happens.

Comment: How the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions should be configured then? Is it still 'view.bounds.size', while 'view' being property of viewController? 
Or instead of 'view' i should somehow get the B view with image and emoji?

Comment: I don't think you totally understand what your code above does :) Basically, you are outputting the whole view hierarchy into an image. Since you now want the B view's hierarchy (instead of view A - which is the main view), you pass the view B's bounds and ask view B to draw its hierarchy. Does that make sense to you? I'll add some code if that doesn't make sense ...

Comment: me, not understating code - is always an option, for sure. 
So instead of writing 'view.bounds.size' i will write 'viewB.bounds.size', where 'viewB' - is a reference to view B ? 
I would appreciate if you can include that implementation.

Comment: Exactly - I mean instead of `view.bounds`, you'd say `viewB.bounds` where viewB is a reference to that particular view. Also, you'd say `viewB.drawHierarchy` in the next line. I'll edit my answer to add some code.

Comment: Thanks Fahim, your solution worked. 
However, as usual in developing, I faced new bug: the pan gesture isn't working. I created a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940186/uipangesturerecognizer-isnt-firing-up-swift-3

Comment: Happy to help, @Evgeny :) Will take a new look at the question if somebody hasn't already answered - just waking up ...