# UIPanGestureRecognizer isn't firing up. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

My view hierarchy is following:

- View

  - View For User's Img + Emoji (A)
  - View With UI elements. (B)

In viewDidLoad, I create UIImageViews for emojis, add them to the A and add gesture recognizers (pan,pinch,rotate):

```
 let emojiView = UIImageView(image: emoji)
            emojiView.tag = n
            emojiView.frame = CGRect(x: 153, y: 299, width: 70, height: 70)
            emojiView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(recognizer:)))
            pan.delegate = self
            emojiView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

            let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePinch(recognizer:)))
            pinch.delegate = self
            emojiView.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

            let rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleRotate(recognizer:)))
            rotate.delegate = self
            emojiView.addGestureRecognizer(rotate)
```

Later, I declare IBActions:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.viewForImgAndEmoji)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.viewForImgAndEmoji)
}

@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    let pinchPoint = recognizer.location(in: viewForImgAndEmoji)
    let ourEmojiView = viewForImgAndEmoji.hitTest(pinchPoint, with: nil)

    ourEmojiView!.transform = ourEmojiView!.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1

}

@IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

    let rotatePoint = recognizer.location(in: viewForImgAndEmoji)
    let ourEmojiView = viewForImgAndEmoji.hitTest(rotatePoint, with: nil)

    ourEmojiView!.transform = ourEmojiView!.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
    recognizer.rotation = 0
}
```

Problem: the pan func isn't firing up. Rotate and pinch works. But panning isn't. 
(Can't disable user interaction for overlaying view since it has buttons)

Comment: Is it possible to get a small demo project with the code? In such situations, it's easier to debug with an actual project which replicates the scenario since (barring something simple that was overlooked) some other view might be swallowing your pan gesture. Or, you can try to replicate the scenario with a single view on your own (instead of multiple overlaid views) and see if the issue still occurs ...

Comment: https://github.com/flostik2008/Skirt
File EmojiVC.swift. Thank you.

Comment: Taking a look now. Will get back to you as soon as I discover what is going on.

Comment: I found the issue and added an answer but do let me know if I wasn't clear about what is going on - I might not be explaining this clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I took a look at the code and I see two possible issues:

1: You have pinch, pan, and rotate gesture recognizers set in the storyboard as well. These might be superfluous. Just mentioning that. This really isn't the issue your pan gesture recognizer isn't working though.

2: The `UIView` for controls covers your emoji and image view and will take over touches. You don't need a full-screen view for the UI controls since you don't seem to do anything with the view itself. Instead, you can simply put the button at the right position on the main screen over the `viewForImgAndEmoji`. This way, any on screen touches reach `viewForImgAndEmoji` except at the spots where you have the buttons.

I modified the storyboard that way and I could get the pan gestures fine at that point. Do let me know if you need me to clarify anything since I am not sure if I was clear enough about the issue :)

**Note:** One issue that you will run into when you fix the above is that you will find that not all touches register because the gesture recognizer is attached to each sticker and the sticker itself might be too small to detect something like a pinch gesture. You might be better off adding `viewForImgAndEmoji` as the gesture handler and activating each sticker/emoji as the recipient of the the gesture based on selecting the emoji by a tap before you try to pinch, rotate, or pan. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Just to clarify, the buttons should go on the main view but *above* the `viewForImgAndEmoji` and not as subviews of `viewForImgAndEmoji` - this way, the buttons still would not appear in your final generated image.

Comment: It worked. I also registered viewForImgAndEmoji as gesture handler, however, since that view also contained user's img, it started to pan/pinch/rotate together with emoji. Therefore, I had to restructure my views to have user img - in a separate view. It was easy, because after your explanation in previous question I now understand how view hierarchy works (for my case).

Comment: Great to hear that you were able to get things working and happy to have been of some assistance :) Good luck with the app and do feel free to ping me if you run into any issues!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to implement the following delegate method:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```